# Appetite for the Unnatural and Clone Legion vs. hexproof creatures

Tags: magic-the-gathering

[Clone Legion](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bClone%20Legion%5d)

> For each creature target player controls, create a token that's a copy of that creature.

[Appetite for the Unnatural](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bAppetite%20for%20the%20Unnatural%5d)

> Destroy target artifact or enchantment. You gain 2 life.

Will this effect an enchantment on a creature which has hexproof?

Comment: @GendoIkari Targeting the player is not directly covered in the linked question, may not be enough to save this on it's own but worth considering.

Answer (score 4):

From the [Comprehensive Rules](http://media.wizards.com/2018/downloads/MagicCompRules%2020181005.txt):

> 702.11b “Hexproof” on a permanent means “This permanent can’t be the target of spells or abilities your opponents control.”

[Appetite for the Unnatural](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bAppetite%20for%20the%20Unnatural%5d) targets the *enchantment*, not the creature itself, so it will resolve and destroy the enchantment (unless the enchantment itself somehow has hexproof too).

[Clone Legion](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bClone%20Legion%5d) targets a player, not creatures, so unless that *player* has hexproof, it will make a copy of all their creatures, including the ones with hexproof. Any enchantments on those creatures won't be copied.

Comment: Hexproof or shroud on auras is rare, you'd need something like [Privileged Position](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=privileged+position) to create that situation, but it is possible, as for players something like [Leyline of Sanctity] (http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=397677)

Comment: Yeah, it's rare. I was thinking of [Diplomatic Immunity](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=19576) which probably has a hexproof variant as well.